# Loop a mp3 file in an Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

This is one of my very first attempts (besides [Purge time](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08SNST1X9) I made before)

I want to play an mp3 file until I ask Alexa to stop. This is was I have so far (The same code I used for the Purge one)

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const Util = require('./util.js');

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const audioUrl = Util.getS3PreSignedUrl("Media/white_noise_500_hz_formatted.mp3").replace(/&/g,'&amp;');
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(`<audio src="${audioUrl}"/>`)
                .getResponse();
    }
};

exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom().addRequestHandlers(LaunchRequestHandler).lambda();
```

As a complete noob, I'm a bit lost. I'd need to wait to put the MP3 in a queue before it finishes or something.

Any idea is welcome, thanks!

PS. I know there are skills for white noise and rain sounds and so on, this one if for learning purposes :D

Answer (score 0):

Where you're using it as a speak item, you're limited to 240 seconds and have to send the whole thing.

You want the audio player directive. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html